# Send Complex Object FROM Flex to PHP

Tags: php, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I want to be able to send complex data from Flex to PHP and be able to parse that data via PHP script. I'm able to send a basic key value pair object but anything more complex than that doesn't translate accordingly.

This works...

```
ht.send({label:"FOO", label2:"FAA", label3:"FII", label4:"FEE"});
```

It translates as expected

This doesn't work...

```
ht.send({obj11:{label:"FOO", label2:"FAA"}, obj2:{label3:"FII", label4:"FEE"}});
```

It is posted as a string `[object][object]`.

Is it possible to send complex data to PHP? I've tried `JSON.encode(object)`. Do I need to send XML instead?

Comment: Corey, Thx. No. Are there any special requirements to use AMF?

Comment: The_asMan. Thx. Can you provide an example. I've tried that but maybe I did it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Json didn't work because you didn't set it up correctly

```
var myComplexObject:Object ={obj11:{label:"FOO", label2:"FAA"}, obj2:{label3:"FII", label4:"FEE"}}

var dataToSend:Object = { data: JSON.encode(myComplexObject) }

ht.send(dataToSend);



// on the php side you will have something like so

$data = json_decode(  $_POST['data'] );

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $data );
```

Comment: The_asMan - You are thee Man! 2 days breaking my head on this!

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using AMF instead of JSON, given it's native support in Flex.

If you are working with large datasets, I have found AMF more effective, but at the end of the day it boils down to what you're most comfortable with. AMF will be easier to work with in Flex, though.

Interesting reads:

http://web.archive.org/web/20090129160211/http://www.5etdemi.com/blog/archives/2006/12/clearing-the-fud-on-amfphps-speed-versus-json-and-xml/

http://web.archive.org/web/20090210160254/http://blogs.adobe.com/mikepotter/2006/07/php_and_flex_js.html